# How can I connect to my school network on Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wpa, wpa2-psk

I want to connect to my school wifi network, which is WPA2 Enterprise with PEAP, using Linux.

On Windows it's easy because it is already configured by my administrator. I have tried using the network GUI on Linux to connect, but without luck. This is the setup I have tried (with some variations):
[image: link to screenshot]

When I try connecting using the above setup, it just says "Connecting..." and then it prompts me for "a password or encryption key", I then type in my password (the one I use to log in to Windows), then it just says "Connecting..." again and the same thing happens over and over. I don't know if something is wrong with my setup or with Linux, but I think it's my setup, since the same thing happens on iPhone.

Anyway, I figured I could just export the settings from Windows, so I did `netsh wlan export` in CMD and got this file:

```
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
<name>Osloskolen</name>
<SSIDConfig>
<SSID>
<hex>4F736C6F736B6F6C656E</hex>
<name>Osloskolen</name>
</SSID>
<nonBroadcast>false</nonBroadcast>
</SSIDConfig>
<connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
<connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
<autoSwitch>false</autoSwitch>
<MSM>
<security>
<authEncryption>
<authentication>WPA2</authentication>
<encryption>AES</encryption>
<useOneX>true</useOneX>
</authEncryption>
<PMKCacheMode>enabled</PMKCacheMode>
<PMKCacheTTL>720</PMKCacheTTL>
<PMKCacheSize>128</PMKCacheSize>
<preAuthMode>disabled</preAuthMode>
<OneX xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/OneX/v1">
<maxAuthFailures>1</maxAuthFailures>
<authMode>machine</authMode>
<EAPConfig>
<EapHostConfig xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
<EapMethod>
<Type xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">25</Type>
<VendorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorId>
<VendorType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorType>
<AuthorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</AuthorId>
</EapMethod>
<Config xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
<Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
<Type>25</Type>
<EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV1">
<ServerValidation>
<DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>false</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>
<ServerNames/>
<TrustedRootCA>
  <!-- Removed in case it's confidential, but the format was like d2 a1 bb ... -->
</TrustedRootCA>
<TrustedRootCA>
  <!-- Removed in case it's confidential, but the format was like d2 a1 bb ... -->
</TrustedRootCA>
</ServerValidation>
<FastReconnect>true</FastReconnect>
<InnerEapOptional>false</InnerEapOptional>
<Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
<Type>26</Type>
<EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsChapV2ConnectionPropertiesV1">
<UseWinLogonCredentials>true</UseWinLogonCredentials>
</EapType>
</Eap>
<EnableQuarantineChecks>false</EnableQuarantineChecks>
<RequireCryptoBinding>false</RequireCryptoBinding>
<PeapExtensions>
<PerformServerValidation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2">true</PerformServerValidation>
<AcceptServerName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2">false</AcceptServerName>
</PeapExtensions>
</EapType>
</Eap>
</Config>
</EapHostConfig>
</EAPConfig>
</OneX>
</security>
</MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

What does this information mean? How can I use it to connect from Linux? Is there a Linux equivalent of `netsh wlan add profile`? Or a way to translate this file to a Linux `system-connections` file?

I do have a username and password, which I believe should be used in addition to the info above. I would be very happy if anyone could help me.

**Edit:** [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/Q1ePDUjn) is the log I get when trying to connect, can anyone help me understand what goes wrong? I copied everything from when I tapped connect to when it prompted me for key again (approximately). This specific time I tried username "Osloskole\tord0505", but otherwise I used the setup from the picture.

Comment: Does your school allow you connect to the wifi?

Comment: @Burgi Yes they do, but they don't have any pre made settings for Linux, only for Windows

Comment: I'm reading the log -- it says that the regular authentication _succeeded_, but the server wants something additional. Probably the "oneX" thing, which I'm guessing is the computer's _own_ AD domain credentials.

Comment: Okay, I have full admin access to my windows computer file system, is there any way to find this and use it in Linux?

Comment: ...wait, no, "OneX" probably just refers to 802.1X -- that is, WPA-Enterprise itself. Still, the wpa_supplicant logs show something is missing, but it's not the password nor the CA cert.

Comment: @grawity Do you think it could be related to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap)? I'm not using Ubuntu though

Answer (score 1):

The username and password need to be obtained from network administrators. If your computer is joined to an AD domain, then they *should* be the same as ones used for Windows.

```
<UseWinLogonCredentials>true</UseWinLogonCredentials>
```

Otherwise, if your school has a "student information" website that uses a login & password, try using that.

The correct CA certificate can be taken from the `<TrustedRootCA>` tags (after converting hex to binary). That's not the main problem here, though, since iOS doesn't check the server cert against a CA at all (it just remembers the first one it sees).

---

Authentication on Linux is handled by wpa_supplicant; to enable its debug mode use one of:

```
busctl set-property fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1 fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 DebugLevel s debug

gdbus call -y -d fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 -o /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1 -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 DebugLevel "<'debug'>"
```

Afterwards run `journalctl -f -u wpa_supplicant` and watch what it prints while trying to connect. (To disable the logging, set it back to `info`.)

Comment: The username and password I am using is the same for logging in on Windows as logging in on our website. How can I convert the hex certificates to binary? And what format should they be saved in? Is it .crt or something else? And what should the files look like?

Comment: .crt isn't a format... If you have `xxd` (from vim), use `xxd -r -p < cert_in_hex.txt > cert_in_binary.crt` and then _probably_ `openssl x509 -inform DER < cert_in_binary.crt > cert_in_base64.pem`.

Comment: OK, which of the <TrustedRootCA> entries should I use? Does it matter?

Comment: Try either of them, or possibly both in a single .pem file -- the school probably included in the profile both the current CA and a backup alternative.

Comment: How should I seperate them if I use both in a single file? Line break?

Answer (score 0):

well i had the very same problem as , but in time i noticed that i enabled network  proxy,
then in many scenarios i have notice that the username can be applied to anonymous identity , for me it worked , try it
which means your anonymous id will be your username
and finally after that you will be connected and everything looks fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Automatic Wireless Connection when Login**

For cases where you would like to login automatically to a wireless router here are the steps:

1. Open the `interface` file:

> ```
> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
> ```

2. Add the following information (Assuming your interface is called wlan0):

> ```
> auto wlan0
>
> iface wlan0 inet static
>
> address ASSIGNED_IP
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> gateway THE_GATEWAY
>
> wireless-essid YOURSSID
>
> wireless-key WIRELESSKEY_HERE
> ```

3. Save the file and reboot computer.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with my problem

Comment: @tjespe i understand you want a GUI solution, so this makes me wonder then. You know how to get on the network, but you just want to do it in a frontend way...hmmm

Comment: No @DeerSpotter The problem is that the network has PEAP protection, so I need more than just SSID and key